# What are the dedicated command line options for `curl -X`?

Tags: curl, api

In my `curl` man pages:

> -X, --request 
> (...)
> Normally you don't need this option. All sorts of GET, HEAD, POST and PUT requests are rather
> invoked by using **dedicated command line options**.

What are the dedicated command line options for `curl -X`?

For example, what is the alternative to `curl -X POST`?

Answer (score 1):

When doing HTTP with curl, the `-X` option changes the actual method string in
the HTTP request. **That’s all it does** - changes one word in the request header.

It’s useful when you want to send a DELETE method or TRACE or similar that curl
has no native support for, for example a custom FTP command to use instead of
the default LIST command.

It does not change the behavior of `curl` in any other way, which makes it possible
to royally confuse `curl` and even cause timeouts.

It's very easy to misuse. For example, `curl -X HEAD` does not give any output because,
by default, curl does not print headers if the switch `-i` is not specified.

Useful reference : [Unnecessary use of curl -X](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/).